# Transition Matrix Operation in Stoikov's Micro Price Paper

Tags: markov, transition-matrix

Sasha Stoikov's [paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2970694) provides an interesting finite state approach to modeling the mid. It makes good sense to me except one property.

On page 7 of the [linked paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2970694), $$G^1(x)=\left(\sum_s\mathbf{Q}^{s-1}\mathbf{R}\right)\mathbf{K}=(1-\mathbf{Q})^{-1}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{K},$$ where $\mathbf{Q}$ is the $nm\times nm$ transition matrix of the transient states and $\mathbf{R}$ the $nm\times 4$ transition matrix of the absorbing states. In my mind, the full transition matrix should look like the following:

$$\mathbf{T}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\mathbf{Q}&\mathbf{R}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{I}\\\end{array}\right),$$

which does agree with [Sasha's own beamer](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/seminars_events/fileupload/4044_Microprice_Michigan.pdf).

**Question:** What is the property applied here so that $\sum_s\mathbf{Q}^{s-1}\mathbf{R}=(1-\mathbf{Q})^{-1}\mathbf{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain).